# Getting multidimensional array from right table results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables. The first one is customer information and the second is phone numbers. 
So in the first table I would have:

```
ID   Name
1    John
2    jill
```

In the second table I would have:

```
ID    phone     ext   notes                  customerID
1     687-5309  20    Primary                1   
2     687-5310  55    John's cell phone      1
3     687-5311  18    Note! Emergency Only!  1
4     235-1189                               2 
5     235-2324  24     title:owner           2
```

When I query it I would like it give me a multidimensional result from the right table. So the result would be:

```
[ID]=>1
[Name]=>John
[phoneList]=>[ 
     [
          [ID]=>1 , [phone]=>687-5309 , [ext]=>20 , [notes]=>Primary ],
          [ID]=>2 , [phone]=>687-5310] , [ext]=>55 , [notes]=>John's cell phone ], 
          [ID]=>3 , [phone]=>687-5311] , [ext]=>18 , [notes]=>Note! Emergency Only! ],
     ]

]
```

So far this is as far as I can get:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_info
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT * 
 FROM phone_numbers
) WHERE ID=1
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible. But it feels like it should be.

Comment: Which version of MySql?  Can you use [those JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) in your version?

Comment: I am running 
Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

So it should work but I get the error:
#1305 - FUNCTION myDatabase.JSON_OBJECTAGG does not exist

Comment: Looks like MariaDB doesn't have that JSON_OBJECTAGG function yet? Reference [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/)

Comment: `JOIN` needs an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without grouping on the customer_info it would just be a simple LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT cust.*, phone.ID AS phone_id, phone.phone, phone.ext, phone.notes
FROM customer_info AS cust
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers AS phone ON phone.customerID = cust.ID
WHERE cust.ID = 1;
```

But if you want one record per customer_info ID?
Then you could also `GROUP BY` the customer_info and then use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) to get 1 string with the phone id's and the phone numbers.

```
SELECT cust.ID, cust.Name, 
 group_concat(concat(phone.ID,':',concat_ws(',', phone.phone, ifnull(phone.ext,''), phone.notes)) separator ';') AS phoneList
FROM customer_info AS cust
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers AS phone ON phone.customerID = cust.ID
WHERE cust.ID = 1
GROUP BY cust.ID, cust.Name;
```

And if the JSON_OBJECT ([MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_object/), [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object)) function is available in your version, then one could use that.

```
SELECT cust.ID, cust.Name, 
group_concat(JSON_OBJECT('id', phone.ID, 'phone', phone.phone, 'ext', phone.ext, 'notes', phone.notes)) AS phoneList
FROM customer_info AS cust
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers AS phone ON phone.customerID = cust.ID
WHERE cust.ID = 1
GROUP BY cust.ID, cust.Name;
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a86a0dd82822ae0f6a99e6a55d36afa2)*

Comment: I'm trying to avoid concat as the data I'm working with is significantly more complex and may have space, dash, quote marks, etc that have to be separated. Since the final 'phone_numbers' table will have a 'contact name', 'notes', 'extension', etc columns.

Comment: I've updated original question to reflect more columns.

Comment: @Robbie Updated. The JSON_OBJECT function works both in MySql 8.x and MariaDB >= 10.2.3

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.